# Graphite : invalid line received from client (codahale metrics)

Tags: metrics, graphite, codahale-metrics

I received errors in carbon when trying to using [metrics for graphite](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/manual/graphite/) :

```
[listener] invalid line received from client HOST:PORT, ignoring
```

So, I tried to add some logs in /opt/graphite/lib/carbon/protocols.py like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27386026/1991579).

And I see in logs this errors:

```
28/07/2015 10:21:14 :: [listener] invalid line - [ tta(S'com.unnyworld.db.dbclient.request_time.auth.max' ]
28/07/2015 10:21:14 :: [listener] invalid line - [ (L1438078874L ]
28/07/2015 10:21:14 :: [listener] invalid line - [ S'5' ]
```

And if we looking for normal request, it looks like:

```
28/07/2015 10:31:07 :: [listener] nice line - [ stats.counters.statsd.bad_lines_seen.rate 0 1438079468 ]
```

What's problem here? Is it carbon problem? Or is it metrics problem? And how can I resolve it?

Metrics version is 3.1.2

Carbon version 0.9.x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My mistake. I sent data to 2003 port, but it's only for plain text.

You should use 2004 port if using pickle protocol, like mentioned [here](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/feeding-carbon.html).

Comment: I'm curious why you preferred pickle over line protocol. The metric name is still duplicated in each sample in pickle, so there will be no obvious network savings.

Comment: @SergeiRodionov cause I can send batches in one go

Comment: What about latency? Is there a background thread to flush metrics that have accumulated in List<MetricTuple> list and are sitting there because the list size is below DEFAULT_BATCH_SIZE?

Comment: @SergeiRodionov dropwizard metrics has background thread. And you set period for sending metrics.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know. Max latency == background thread flush period. Thanks.